# How does this function translate to an Angular (5) class?

Tags: javascript, angular

So I wrote myself a tool in javascript and jQuery, but now I want to translate it into Angular. I'm yet to start, but I'm curious what this would look like.

Could anybody be so kind to translate the following code below to an Angular class?

```
var Demo = (function(){
    return {
        TryOut: tryOut
    };

    function tryOut(userId, someText){
        console.log(userId);
        console.log(someText);
    }
})();

Demo.TryOut(5, "This is random text");
```

if not everything is correct, that's fine. I'm just really curious what I'm for, since I couldn't find a guide on making a function that returns functions.

Btw feel free to add some TypeScript in there, since that's what my intentions are as well.

Comment: Angular class? You are getting the whole idea wrong my friend. Angular uses decorators, which are essentially function wrappers, but the classes are from the ES6 update. Typescript is literally types for javascript, it is not related to the classes feature of ES6

Comment: By the way i don't see why you didn't use a more straightforward syntax, like `var Demo = { TryOut: function tryOut(userId, someText){ /* code */ } };`? if you don't use prototypes or applying context, i see no reason

Answer (score 1):

Classes are coming from ES6 not angular. Typescript makes it easy to type your objects. Your ES6 class would look like this:

```
class Demo {
    tryOut(userId, someText){
        console.log(userId);
        console.log(someText);
    }
}

let demo = new Demo();
demo.tryOut(1, "world");
```

Which will generate the following JS code:

```
var Demo = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Demo() {
    }
    Demo.prototype.tryOut = function (userId, someText) {
        console.log(userId);
        console.log(someText);
    };
    return Demo;
}());
var demo = new Demo();
demo.tryOut(1, "world");
```

You can try this out yourself below. There are also other learning options in the dropdown list.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html